# Convert local time string to UTC with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert a local time string and a timezone to UTC time. So far I am using the following code to format:

```
<localtime>2019-12-02T06:46:24.000</localtime>
<timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
```

The following will work only if as timezone I would use something like: **PT0H**

```
<xsl:variable name="ztime">
            <xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($localTime, $timezone)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Is there any way to get the time offset from the timezone name?

Comment: I think there web services like https://timezonedb.com/api which you can "call" using `doc` from XSLT to pass in your time zone description and get back a result with the time zone offset.

Comment: You may be able to get the offset using the `format-dateTime()` function in XPath/XSLT 3.0. Note that this works in the opposite direction - i.e. adjusts the given datetime to the named timezone - so this would be only the beginning of the calculation. -- Note also that the offset depends not only on the timezone, but also on the date and the time - for example, the offset in your example is 8 hours, but it will be 7 hours for a date in the summer.

Comment: Advice, irrelevant to your question: don't use `xsl:variable/xsl:value-of/@select` when `xsl:variable select="..."` would do just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some XSLT processors may recognize an IANA time-zone name (Olson timezone) in the fifth ($place) argument of format-dateTime() - this was introduced in XSLT 3.0 timeframes. You can't use that directly in `adjust-dateTime`, but with appropriate formatting parameters you could use format-dateTime() to convert the IANA time-zone to a real offset. Though daylight savings remains an issue: there's nothing in the system to tell you whether your local time is in summer or winter time.

If you're using Saxon then there are some extensions available (requiring Saxon-PE or higher). See `saxon:adjust-to-civil-time()` and `saxon:in-summer-time()`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation